# Best way to merge without fast forward with same heads on Git

Tags: git, merge

The problem is I need to integrate external changes to our project, those external files don't use Git. Since I pasted their code on a new brach ('theirs' derived from 'dev') and tried to merge those changes in a new branch ('merge-test'), Git is doing a Fast Forward merge (simple replacement) because both branches have the latest dev's HEAD. I need it applies conflict resolution instead like it would do if those changes had been done using our local repo within Git (for example recursive).

I know there are merge strategies to choose in merge command, but since I never used them, what would be the safest command to merge here? Note this is not a question regarding the --no-ff flag (as I believe it is only for notation adjustement upon commit). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: When you make the "merge-test" branch, branch it off from the point the other party started working, not the latest branch. Git, unlike SVN, performs a 3-way merge for conflicts, and without the proper base it doesn't see the "conflict"

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sadly, I didn't have any git branch with the other party's code, as I tried to expose at:

_those external files don't use Git._

Comment: In that case, git cannot assist you with the merge, run `diff file1 file2` to zee the differences and do a "manual merge"

Comment: See my answer with solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution that I found out and worked for me (with example namings):

1. Running `git checkout --orphan external-project-flow` (this successfully creates a new branch without files and totally empty commit history)
2. Pasting their code (with same files hierarchy than ours) onto that branch, and make a commit.
3. Checking out `dev` branch back
4. Making a new branch from there: `git checkout -B merge-test`
5. Running the merge: `git merge external-project-fow`. This resulted in the recursive merge instead of the fast forward one, that I was looking for. This also added to the files the conflict lines indications.

As a side note, I gave up this integration technique since there were a lot of conflicts and I didn't want my application failing because the conflict lines. Instead I considered it best to apply the integration file by file manually from another `dev`-based branch. But at least I could still see the changes from the `merge-test` using a certain GUI (of course without actually checking out that branch).